# How to change this frosting recipe to get a thicker result?

Tags: cake, frosting

Making chocolate cake and frosting per recipe below from [Hershey's recipe](https://www.hersheys.com/recipes/recipe-details.aspx?id=96550&name=Gluten-Free-HERSHEY%27S-). The frosting we made is a bit too liquidy to put on the cake, more like icing. is there a way (or even hack) to make it thicker, short of adding a cup of powdered sugar to cut the ratio of the liquid ingredients?

```
"PERFECTLY CHOCOLATE" CHOCOLATE FROSTING
1/2 cup (1 stick) butter or margarine
2/3 cup HERSHEY'S Cocoa
3 cups powdered sugar
1/3 cup milk
1 teaspoon vanilla extract
Melt butter. Stir in cocoa. Alternately add powdered sugar and milk, beating to spreading consistency.
```

Add small amount of additional milk, if needed. Stir in vanilla. About 2 cups frosting.

Comment: Is it still warm? Let it cool a bit?

Comment: Is it solid enough, once set, that you could just apply multiple layers on top of another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cream Cheese.

Whip in as much as you need to...

It won't be perfect Le Cordon Bleu, but it will be pretty good.

Bon Appetit

Comment: My 10 y/o went with this FTW, and Mother's Day was saved.

Answer (score 1):

As with most things, when adding ingredients to correct a problem, do a small test batch and slowly incorporate the ingredients until your desired consistency is achieved.  After you've found a ratio that satisfies you, then mix up the whole batch.

Here are my favorite add-ins for frosting thickness:

**Dairy Alternatives:**

Goat Cheese

Strained sour cream /creme fraiche (strain for 12+ hours; save the whey and use it for making biscuits later!)

Strained super-thick greek yogurt (same note as above)

Cream Cheese (Jolenealaska already suggested, see above)

Powdered milk

Powdered whey protein

Nutella

Dry Pudding Mix

**Non-Dairy Alternatives:**

Non-dairy Dry Pudding Mix

Peanut Butter/Almond Butter/Sunflower Seed Butter/ etc

- these obviously may change the flavor profile if utilized, especially peanut

Avocado

Strained coconut cream 
 - use a nut milk bag to strain/press out liquid...*this can be a pain*

Powdered plant protein powders(hemp/soy/pea/bean)

- when using these, be aware that many of them impart a beany/grassy flavor if used in quantity...just depending on what you select

Black Beans

- I use about 1 T of canned beans without added salt when I do this...but I also run it through my Vitamix, so this solution may not be for you unless you have a powerful food processor/blender

Xanthan/Guar/Locust bean/Methylcellulose/Gelatin

- Use these sparingly, on the order of a few grams...these can be difficult to find if you are not in an area with specialty food markets (like Whole Foods/Trader Joe's)

Comment: I think this will live long as the definitive answer!  Thanks so much